# D3.js How to apply multiple classes when using a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I'm currently using D3.js and have come across a problem that I just can't seem to solve.

I have a CSV that has a column named "Set" and a column named "Year". I want to pull the values from these columns and use them as class names. This is what I currently have...

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", function(d) {
                if (d["Set"] == 1)
                {
                    return "set-1";
                }
                if (d["Set"] == 2)
                {
                    return "set-2";
                }
            });
```

This works perfectly fine and gives each data-point a class name. When I try the following however, the "Set" class names are over written by the "Year" class names.

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", function(d) {
                if (d["Set"] == 1)
                {
                    return "set-1";
                }
                if (d["Set"] == 2)
                {
                    return "set-2";
                }
            .attr("class", function(d) {
                if (d["Year"] == 2012)
                {
                    return "2012";
                }
                if (d["Year"] == 2013)
                {
                    return "2013;
                }
            });
```

How can this code be rectified so that it adds on additional class names as opposed to over-writing them.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery? It has a nice `addClass()` method.

Comment: But how do I access the .CSV and apply the class to the correct data nodes?

Comment: Can you add the class after loading in the CSV file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just want a single function that does both things don't you. Something along these lines perhaps...

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", function(d) {
            var c = "";
            if (d["Set"] == 1)
            {
                c = "set-1";
            }
            if (d["Set"] == 2)
            {
                c = "set-2";
            }
            if (d["Year"] == 2012)
            {
                c += " 2012";
            }
            if (d["Year"] == 2013)
            {
                c += " 2013;
            }
            return c;
        });
```

Comment: You sir are an absolute genius and have saved me a shed load of time.

Comment: You can also concatenate directly: `.attr("class", function(d) { "set-" + d["Set"] + " " + d["Year"] })`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I think you need a `return` in there no..?

Comment: dislike this diy. Much better the OO approach from Pablo and @Ivan

Answer (score 64):

There is an alternative approach that can be useful. You can assign or remove classes from an element using `selection.classed('class-name', true)` or `selection.classed('class-name', false)`:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .classed('2012', function(d) { return d['Year'] === 2012; })
    .classed('2013', function(d) { return d['Year'] === 2013; })
    .classed('set-1', function(d) { return d['Set'] === 1; })
    .classed('set-2', function(d) { return d['Set'] === 2; });
```

I prefer this way because you can remove the classes from an element using the same syntax.

Comment: very nice answer! I like the suggestion of using the smart D3 classed() method. +1!

Comment: an even better reason to use `classed` (instead of `attr('class'...` is that it won't clear other classes already assigned to the element.

Answer (score 18):

#### Update

Seems, this approach no longer acceptable for D3.js v5+

#### Original answer

You can also use a hash as argument of `classed` function:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .classed({
    '2012': function(d) { return d['Year'] === 2012; },
    '2013': function(d) { return d['Year'] === 2013; },
    'set-1': function(d) { return d['Set'] === 1; },
    'set-2': function(d) { return d['Set'] === 2; }
  });
```